# Access $.data() inside a selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<img class="sth" data-number="1" src="sth.jpg" alt="">
```

There are a couple of such elements, and they all differ only in data-number. I want to do the following for all elements:

```
$('.sth').attr('src', 'sth' + data('number') + '.jpg');
```

so that every image changes the src with its own number.

However, data('number') does not work, and $('.sth').data('number') changes all with sth1.jpg.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, using the jquery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function like so:

```
$('.sth').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'sth' + $(this).data('number') + '.jpg');
});
```

Which will execute on each element matched by the `.sth` selector.

Comment: This is right: The original author was almost doing it correctly when they did `$('.sth').data('number')`, but using `each()` will evaluate each instance of '.sth' separately.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) function

```
$('.sth').attr('src', function(){
    return 'sth' + $(this).data('number') + '.jpg';
});
```